# how to get the order of named arguments after a call the function

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a function with named arguments

```
def sample(a=None, b=None, c=None)
    pass
```

how to get the order of these arguments after a call the function?

```
sample(b=1, a=1, c=1)
out: ['b', 'a', 'c']

sample(c=1, a=1)
out: ['c', 'a']

sample(a=1, b=1)
out: ['a', 'b']

sample(b=1, a=1)
out: ['b', 'a']

sample(a=1, b=1, c=1)
out: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

maybe this can be done using a decorator or some other way?

*updated:*

I want to make the wrapper for elasticsearch filters like sqlalchemy filter way but through named arguments

```
class ESQuery(object):
    def __init__(self, url, index):
        pass

    def filter(self, _bool=None, _range=None, _not=None, _and=None, _or=None, _type=None, exists=None, query=None):
        return self.query_body
```

after calling the function, I need to get the correct order of query, like this http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-and-filter.html

I just can't build the query so that to keep a strict order

```
es = Someclass(url, index)
es.filter()
```

I want to do it using named arguments that people find it convenient to use as the tooltip

update 2:

I want to find another way, one line is not enough, as there can be long calls

```
from api.search_api import ESQuery
es = ESQuery(index='lot', place='etsy_spider', match_all=True)
print es.\
    filter(query='{ "tweet": "full text search" }').\
    filter(_range='{ "created": { "gte": "now - 1d / d" }}').\
    filter(should='{ "term": { "featured": true }},')
```

maybe some ideas on how to simplify long queries in elasticsearch?

Comment: Can you give an example where this information would be useful?

Comment: as far as I know this would not be possible, since named arguments are processed as dictionaries internally, which don't have an order

Comment: Well for simple cases one way would be to read the function invocation line from the calling frame and parse it using regex or something else, but this won't work properly if the function invocation spans over multiple lines.

Comment: I've updated the question, the version of python is not important

Comment: @Lucian Why the version is not important? What if I give you a Python 3.5 solution that won't work with the version of Python you are using.

Comment: I will use the new version if required

Comment: I think your last example essentially contains the solution: on calling `.filter(...)`, `ESQuery` should keep an ordered list of filters and build Elasticsearch' query by  `AND`ing these in order. However, AND should be commutative, why does the order matter?

Comment: just I don't know how to operate the nested brackets {} to close them where necessary

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a reason why it would be useful. That being said, you can use the `inspect` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html):

```
import inspect

def f(a=2, b=3):
    call_string = inspect.stack()[1][4] ## returns a list with the string that represents how the function was called.
    print call_string
    args, kwargs = get_function_args(call_string[0]) ## to return what you want
    ...

f(b=3, a=1) # prints [u'f(b=3, a=1)\n']
```

Then, you would parse the `call_string` with regular expressions.

Note that this method only works for single-line calls.

And here is a simple regex parser that will return a list of arguments and keyword arguments by order of appearance. Note that this is very basic and will not work with strings that contain ",".

```
import re

VALID_VAR = "([_A-Za-z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)"
LEFT_PAR = '\('
RIGHT_PAR = '\)'

def get_function_args(line):
    args = []
    keywords = []
    res = re.search(VALID_VAR+LEFT_PAR+'(.*?)'+RIGHT_PAR+'$', line)
    if res:

        allargs = res.group(2)
        allargs = allargs.split(',') ## does not work if you have strings with ","

        for arg in allargs:

            ## Arguments
            res2 = re.search('^{0}$'.format(VALID_VAR), arg.strip())
            if res2:
                args.append(res2.group(1))
            ## Optional arguments
            res2 = re.search('^{0} *= *(.*)$'.format(VALID_VAR), arg.strip())
            if res2:
                keywords.append(res2.group(1))

    return args, keywords
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438746/how-to-get-the-order-of-named-arguments-after-a-call-the-function#comment47046374_29438746) as well this won't work with something like `f(a=1,\nb=3)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Fair enough

Comment: Two things: first, I wouldn't use that technique in any sort of production code as it breaks when splitting the call over multiple lines, like Ashwini mentioned. Second, the parsing function is massive overkill - all you need is the _order_ of the arguments, you don't need to parse it again. Simply use a state machine or a regex to filter out commas that are not delimiting function arguments (those inside "", [], (), {}), and then figure out the order of the actual arguments received by determining the positions of `"{key}="` for all keys in `kwargs`.

Comment: @l4mpi yes, I agree with both points. For the first one, I added that it only worked in simple cases. About the second point, I just re-used some old code that did a little more than this.

Comment: Well you're doing lots of hard work here, simply tokenize the line: https://gist.github.com/ashwch/4387c22de1eefc19879f

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Nice!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it can be done - read on.

> how to get the order of these arguments after a call the function?

Named arguments are passed as a dictionary, whose `.items()` by definition are in [arbitrary order](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
# this...
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    ...
# .... is the equivalent of:
def foo(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a')
    b = kwargs.get('b')
    c = kwargs.get('c')  
    ...
```

> how to get the order of these arguments after a call the function?

Regardless of the above, you can achieve it by using an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def bar(sorted_kwargs):
      for k in sorted_kwargs.keys():
        print 'index of %s => %s' % (k, sorted_kwargs.keys().index(k))
bar(OrderedDict((('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3))))
# results
index of c => 0
index of a => 1
index of b => 2
```

> maybe this can be done using a decorator or some other way?

The order of the arguments is something for the caller to decide -- a decorator cannot change that.

Btw. there is a draft [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/) about this

Comment: thanks you guys for the downvotes. maybe you can add some comments so I can improve the post?